# How to use Angular setter when Input changed?

Tags: angular, setter, eventsetter

I have two components `Parent Component` and `Child component`, I have an API that takes place in the `Parent component` and the response value is passed to the `child component`. currently I am using `ngOnChanges` but I want to know how to use `Setters` instead.

assume In the `ParentComponent` I have the below code:

```
<ChildComponent [apiResponse]="res" />
```

and in the `ChildComponent` I have this:

```
@Input() apiResponse: any;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(this.apiResponse)
}
```

Every time the `apiResponse` changed the `ngOnChanges` function will fire and prints the value in the console.

if I want to achieve the result but with the use if `Setters`. as in other scenario I might have multiple inputs and I don't want `ngOnChanges` to get fired every time an input's value changed.

Comment: It may help you https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of:

```js
@Input() apiResponse: any;
```

Use:

```js
@Input() 
get apiResponse(): any {return this._apiResponse;}
set apiResponse(value: any) {
  this._apiResponse = value;
  console.log(value);
  // do whatever else you want to do here
}
private _apiResponse: any;
```

In the code above, the only really necessary part is the setter function. Without that, you cannot pass in the values from the parent components via `@Input()`'s.  The rest is just a matter of what you want. For example, if you want to save the value to use it later, you need the private member (or a `BehaviorSubject` or anything you think it's good for storing a value):

```js
@Input() 
set apiResponse(value: any) {
  this._apiResponse$.next(value);
  console.log(value);
  // do whatever else you want to do here
}
_apiResponse$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
```

In the example above, notice that I haven't made the subject a private member. I suppose you want to use it in the template, so, even though it should be private (not part of the component API), I can't do that because the template needs to access it. The underscore is something to indicate that such a public member is not part of the API.

Comment: can you please use `BehaviorSubject ` to save the data?